# Silverlight JetPack Theme Toolkit errors

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

After creating a new Silverlight application from the JetPack theme template that was installed, I try to follow the instructions provided in the App.xaml file about how to enable themeing of silverlight toolkit controls,

```
            <!--
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/ToolkitStyles.xaml"/>
            To extend this theme to include the toolkit controls:
            1. Install the Silverlight Toolkit for Silverlight 4
            2. Add a Toolkit control to your project from the toolbox. This will add references to toolkit assemblies.
            3. Change the "Build Action" for ToolkitStyles.xaml to "Page"
            4. Uncomment the resource dictionary include above.

            If you do not intend to use toolkit controls, delete this comment and the ToolkitStyles.xaml file.-->
```

I follow the instructions correctly but the project now does not compile, here are the 39 or so errors it throws out.

I'm new to Silverlight (coming from MVC/jQuery) and it might be something I'm doing.

> Error 40  An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "Assets/ToolkitStyles.xaml".    X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\app.xaml    18  17  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 20  Assembly 'System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference. Also, verify that your project and all referenced assemblies have been built.    X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1   603 ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 19  Assembly 'System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference. Also, verify that your project and all referenced assemblies have been built.    X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1   421 ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 39  The attachable property 'Effect' was not found in type 'Legend'.    X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   2204    38  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>   Error   34  The attachable property 'IsFieldGroup' was not found in type 'DataField'.   X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1738    27  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 31  The attachable property 'LayoutTransform' was not found in type 'LayoutTransformer'.    X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1619    38  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 13  The property 'IsFieldGroup' does not exist on the type 'Grid' in the XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit'. X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1738    27  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 11  The tag 'AccordionButton' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit'.  X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1622    38  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>   Error   2   The tag 'ButtonSpinner' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit'.    X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   565 26  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 3   The tag 'ButtonSpinner' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit'.    X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   665 26  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 4   The tag 'ButtonSpinner' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit'.    X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   896 26  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>   Error   16  The tag 'EdgePanel' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit'.   X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   2199    34  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 1   The tag 'ExpandableContentControl' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit'. X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   365 34  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>   Error   12  The tag 'ExpandableContentControl' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit'. X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1624    34  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 9   The tag 'LayoutTransformer' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit'.    X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1455    38  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>   Error   10  The tag 'LayoutTransformer' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit'.    X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1618    34  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 17  The tag 'Legend' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit'.   X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   2203    34  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>   Error   5   The tag 'LinearClipper' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit'.  X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   975 26  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 7   The tag 'ListTimePickerPopup' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit'.  X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1122    22  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 14  The tag 'ResourceDictionaryCollection' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit'. X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1960    18  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 6   The tag 'TimePickerPopupTemplate' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit'.  X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1121    18  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 8   The tag 'TimeUpDown' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit'.   X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1230    26  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 15  The tag 'Title' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit'.    X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   2193    30  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 37  The type 'dvp:EdgePanel' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   2199    34  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 25  The type 'prim:LinearClipper' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.  X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   975 26  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 32  The type 'toolkit:AccordionButton' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1622    38  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 22  The type 'toolkit:ButtonSpinner' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   565 26  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 23  The type 'toolkit:ButtonSpinner' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   665 26  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 24  The type 'toolkit:ButtonSpinner' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   896 26  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 21  The type 'toolkit:ExpandableContentControl' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.    X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   365 34  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 33  The type 'toolkit:ExpandableContentControl' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.    X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1624    34  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 29  The type 'toolkit:LayoutTransformer' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1455    38  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 30  The type 'toolkit:LayoutTransformer' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1618    34  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>   Error   38  The type 'toolkit:Legend' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.  X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   2203    34  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 27  The type 'toolkit:ListTimePickerPopup' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1122    22  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 35  The type 'toolkit:ResourceDictionaryCollection' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.    X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1960    18  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 26  The type 'toolkit:TimePickerPopupTemplate' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built. X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1121    18  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 28  The type 'toolkit:TimeUpDown' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.  X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   1230    26  ISMM.SilverlightUI
>
> Error 36  The type 'toolkit:Title' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.   X:\Projects\ISMM\ISMM.SilverlightUI\Assets\ToolkitStyles.xaml   2193    30  ISMM.SilverlightUI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like Toolkit problems. What references have you got in the project?

There are quite a few assemblies that make up the toolkit. Looks like some of them it wants are 'System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit' and 'System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit'. The DockPanel is part of 'System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit' or something similar so that one might have been added when you dragged a DockPanel in.

Comment: Basic references the project template adds itself, I drag a dock panel into the main.xaml file to get the toolkit reference. Is there a specific reference for the toolkit missing?

Comment: D'oh, I just went through using the add reference and see what you mean. Guess the instructions would really need to say, drag several different types of toolkit controls to get the correct assemblies! Thats fixed it now :-)

Comment: Could you please edit some of the content from the comments into the body of the answer so that it's a bit more apparent that this is an answer?  Thanks.

Comment: Done - moved my comments into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I resolved it by adding references to `System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit` and `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit`

Comment: Why would you answer the same thing as the 8 months old accepted answer?